# Get the command that is executed from cmd? using c#

Tags: c#, process, cmd, operating-system

I want an event based function, when user opens cmd and excute command I get the command and process id that start from it. Is their any way any hint

```
if ((((ManagementBaseObject)e["TargetInstance"])["Caption"]).ToString() == "cmd.exe") 
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32((((ManagementBaseObject)e["TargetInstance"])["ProcessID"]));
    Process localByName = Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(id));
}
```

But I want to reverse above that if user open cmd and execute command I can get only command

Comment: You need to attach to every console opened in the desktop or to a particular CMD started by your program?

Comment: check attached to cmd now how to get or convert it to proces and get its command

Comment: look i get the process id and process cmd too but now how to get which command usser is executing after a wait

Comment: You could try by getting al processes that are running continuously (to get new processes), then check if their parent process is a CMD and get the process command line (to get the command that started it)

Comment: no i get the process cmd id now i want to attach an event when ever user open cmd and excute command from it it returns me command that user run in cmd it doesnot matter how many time user open cmd i am attached to every process of cmd so need and event that capture input

Comment: or their is any keylogger that reads the input only entered in console applications